# Как исправить ошибку при запуске тестов django?

Tags: python, django

test_api.py

```
import unittest

from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class MyTestCase(APITestCase):
    def test_get(self):
        url = reverse('articles-list')
        print(url)
        response = self.client.get(url)
        print(response)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Ошибка: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
Данную ошибку я видел и в интернете, но все мои попытки не привели ни к чему

Answer (score 0):

Это должно помочь:

```py
import sys
import os

project = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('manage.py'))
sys.path.append(project)
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "your_project.settings"

import django
django.setup()
```